# Wordpress Menu Styling - disable "active" on the current page

Tags: html, css, wordpress, menu

I need to disable code in a Wordpress Menu. The website is `http://bekim.sk` Currently there is an active menu item called `Domov` (Home).

How do I disable the `active` css class? I tried to look it up in theme CSS files but couldn't find the exact code. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file you are looking for is here:
/wp-content/uploads/link/lmm/lmm_locations.css
Then, line 69, you have the code

```
#lmm.all .navmenu-nav > li > a:hover,
#lmm.all .lmm-navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
#lmm.all .navmenu-nav > li > a:focus,
#lmm.all .lmm-navbar-nav > li > a:focus,
#lmm.all .navmenu-nav > .open > a,
#lmm.all .lmm-navbar-nav > .open > a,
#lmm.all .navmenu-nav > .active > a,
#lmm.all .lmm-navbar-nav > .active > a {
  /* fallback */
  background-color: #404040;
}
```

Modify color here. Or segregate only the code you need from in there and modify it.

Comment: that doesn't fix the `color`, just the `background-color`. that theme uses 2 different rules for changing the bg and text color

Answer (score 1):

You could just override the css, so that the `nav` links don't get re-styled when their parent has the `.active` class.

To do this you'd need to override the styling rule that applies `color` and and `background-color`.

It looks like this rule is affecting `color`:

`#lmm.all .lmm-navbar-nav > .active > a > .lmm-item-content`

and this rule is affecting `background-color`:

`#lmm.all .lmm-navbar-nav > .active > a`

So an override would look like this:

```
#lmm.all .lmm-navbar-nav > .active > a > .lmm-item-content {
    color: #6B6B6B; /*  original link colors */
}

#lmm.all .lmm-navbar-nav > .active > a {
    background-color: #F2F2F2 /* header bg color */
}
```

You could also customize how `.active` displays by using your own rules in the above override, if you desire. Make sure these rules come *after* your main css doc.